# loop not executing last statement in last iteration in C?

Tags: c, for-loop

The for loop is not executing last statement in the loop body, if it is last iteration(or only one iteration). And fails to work properly even if it just contains printf() statements and also skips next coming statements in the function body.Here is the code:

```
void build()
{
    int i;
    system("clear");
    printf("\nBuild the table");
    printf("\n");
    printf("\nMaximum number of entries ------> 20");
    printf("\nHow many do u want------>");
    scanf("%d",&num);
    printf("\nEnter the following items\n");
    for(i=0;i<num;i++)
    {
        printf("\nName ");
        scanf("%s",emp[i].name);        
        printf("\nCode");
        scanf("%ld",&emp[i].code);      
        printf("\nDesignation");
        scanf("%s",emp[i].designation);     
        printf("\nAge");
        scanf("%d",&emp[i].age);        
        printf("\nYears of experience");
        scanf("%d",&emp[i].exp);        
        printf("\nHello everyone");
    }
    for(i=0;i<num;i++)
    {
        printf("\n%s",emp[i].name);
        printf("\n%ld",emp[i].code);
        printf("\n%s",emp[i].designation);
        printf("\n%d",emp[i].age);
        printf("\n%d",emp[i].exp);
    }
    printf("\nGoing to main menu"); 
}


struct employee
{
    char name[20];
    long int code;
    char designation[20];
    int exp,age;
};
struct employee emp[max];
```

I am facing the same problem with both the for loops in the function and above is the structure declaration is  where max=20;

Comment: [Couldn't reproduce](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/IV7AyeysYkcow5Lq). Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Add the newlines at the end of the line instead at the beginning and it will work -- or use fflush(stdout) to force the output you are missing

Comment: Soren,It didn't work with either of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your analysis is wrong -- the problem is not execution but line buffering.

`printf` has several modes for optimization of io -- most commenly misunderstood  is the line buffering which happens to automatically flush when the newline is encountered.

so

```
printf("\nGoing to main menu");
```

would not flush because the newline is not at the end

where

```
printf("Going to main menu\n");
```

would flush.   If you must do it your way  use fflush, like

```
printf("\nGoing to main menu"); 
fflush(stdout);
```

to force flushing

Comment: Hey soren, Thank you. But it doesn't work if i call the function through switch statement

Answer (score 0):

This is a section where a concept of C's surfaces. The situation is, if one doesn't append a new line (`\n`) to a `printf()` statement, then we have problems.

It does depend a lot on the compiler too, but it is a good practice that we append a new line to every `printf()` statement.

So, let the last statement i.e. ***line 33*** changed to the following:

`printf("\nGoing to main menu\n")`

Now the reason why `\n` helps is that on seeing new line the compiler will perform a [flush](https://stackoverflow.com/qpuestions/1716296/why-does-printf-not-flush-after-the-call-unless-a-newline-is-in-the-format-strin). Now having said this if you still persist on having no new lines then have a look at the following code: :)

`printf("\nGoing to main menu")
fflush(stdout);`